# Is $A_n$ uncountable for all $n \in \Bbb N\ $?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, cardinals

[image]

> For all $n \in \Bbb N$ consider the set $A_n = \left \{x \in \Bbb R\ |\ \left (\cos x \right )^n + \left (\sin x \right )^n = 1 \right \}.$ Is $A_n$ uncountanble for all $n \in \Bbb N\ $?

If $n = 2$ then $A_n = \Bbb R$ which is uncountable. How do I prove it for $n \neq 2\ $?

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** $:$ This question is motivated from option $(2)$ of the original question.

Comment: $A_1$ is countable.

Comment: I don't think $A_n$ is uncountable when $n\neq2$. Look at the graph of $\sin(x)^k + \cos(x)^k$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sir how do you say that $A_1$ is countable? Can you please be more explicit? Thanks.

Comment: @YacoubKureh I have added the image of the relevant question. Please have a look at it. This question appeared in CSIR-NTA NET December $2019.$

Comment: The question posed below the picture is not the same as question 2 in the picture.

Comment: @Fenris all the options $(1),(3)$ and $(4)$ are definitely false. Did you observe that? BTW why the downvote? I think people in this website become very notorious and they unreasonably downvoted posts.

Comment: I have asked that question motivated by option $(2)$ @Fenris?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sin x+\cos x=1$ implies that $1=1^{2}=\sin^{2}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)+2\sin (x) \cos (x)$ which gives  $\sin (2x)=0$. Hence $2x$ is a an integer multiple of $\pi$. Hence $A_1$ is countable.

Using Complex Analysis it is easy to see that $A_n$ is uncoutable only for $n=2$. If $A_n$ is uncountable it has  a limit point. A Theorem in Complex Analysis shows that we must have $\cos^{n} x+\sin^{n}x=1$ for all $x$. Put $x=\frac {\pi} 4$ to see that $n=2$.

Real analytic proof for $n$ even: On $A_n$ we have $t^{m}+(1-t)^{m}=1$ wheer $m=\frac n 2$ and $t=\sin ^{2}x$. This equation is a polynomial equation in $t$ and it has only finitely many roots. Hence there are only finite number of possible values for $\sin ^{2}x$ and each of then give only countably many values of $x$.

Comment: Yeah that's a nice argument @KaviRamaMurthy sir. What about $n \gt 2\ $?

Comment: @Phibetakappa $A_n$ is countable for any $n \neq 2$. But I dont have réal analytic proof at the moment. I have added a proof using Complex Analysis.

Comment: Yeah for complex analysis this is a direct consequence of identity theorem. I know that.

Comment: In real anlytic situation this result doesn't hold. Consider for instance the function $f(x) = x\sin \dfrac {1} {x},$ for $x \neq 0$ and equal to $0$ at $x = 0.$ Then the zeros of $f$ are $\left \{\dfrac {1} {n\pi}\ \bigg |\ n \in \Bbb N \right \} \bigcup\ \{0\}$ which has a limit point $0$ but $f \equiv 0$ on $\Bbb R.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ have extension to entire functions on $\mathbb  C$. So my proof is completely valid.

Comment: Yeah I agree that $\sin z$ is the holomorphic extension of $\sin x$ in the entire complex plane. If $\sin z = 0,$ for all $z \in \Bbb C$ then so is $\sin x,$ for all $x \in \Bbb R.$

Comment: @Phibetakappa I have edited my answer again with a real analytic proof for $n$ even.

Comment: Very nice argument @KaviRamaMurthy sir. You used countable union of finite sets is also countable. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple argument to handle all integer coefficients $n>2$ is to remember that

$$\sin^2x + \cos^2x=1$$

holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$, from which follows that $\forall x \in \mathbb R: |\sin x| \le 1, |\cos x| \le1$, so for $n > 2$

$$\sin^n x + \cos^n x \le |\sin x|^n  + |\cos x|^n \le |\sin x|^2  + |\cos x|^2 = \sin^2x + \cos^2x=1,$$

where the second inequality follows form $\forall t \in [0,1]: t^n -t^2= t^2(t^{n-2}-1) \le 0 \Rightarrow t^n \le t^2$. Equality holds only for $t=0$ or $t=1$, so both $|\sin x|$ and $|\cos x|$ have to be $0$ or $1$, which happens only for a countable set of real $x$ (just either one being $0$ or $1$ is already just a countable set).

Comment: Very nice and perhaps the simplest argument! It's elementary Watson! Thanks a lot.